# What is the conversion rate in a chemical reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

Consider the following chemical reaction

$$\ce{X <=>[w_1][w_2] Y}$$

where $w_1$ is called the conversion rate of $X$ to molecule $Y$. What is the exact meaning of this conversion rate? Is it the same as probability?

The reference paper is: 
[Ref](https://ifisc.uib-csic.es/users/raul/CURSOS/SP/Master_equations.pdf)

Comment: Your formula fails to display correctly - please check it thoroughly.

Comment: The coefficients relate to ODEs of the concentrations (or maybe activities). They can also relate to the transition functions between states. Stochiometry makes things complicated - I think they turn the ODE variables into powers of the concentrations, or at least forces them to be multiplied. If you look at the examples at the end the coefficient near the base of the arrow is multiplied with the corresponding concentration.

Comment: I think they might be called transition probability rates or propensities too? Don't quote me on that though.

Answer (score 1):

The paper you linked to pertains to [birth-death processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process). An example of a birth-death process in the physical chemistry context that you're interested in  would be a set of molecules where each molecule is in one of two states, $X$ or $Y$, which are isomers of each other. The model assumes that due to the molecules' environment, each isomer can turn into the other isomer at times that are modeled as being random.

In the paper you provided a link to, $w_1$ is the probability per unit time that within a short period of time $\Delta t \ll 1/w_1$, a given molecule that's in state $X$ will transition to state $Y$. I.e., if a given molecule is in state $X$ at time $t$, then there is a probability of $w_1 \Delta t$ that the molecule will have randomly transitioned to state $Y$ by time $t+\Delta t$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If we assume that $t=5$, then if I want to calculate this probability for $t=6$, what should I do? In other word, what should I do to calculate  the probability that a molecule will go from X to Y for unit time?

Comment: Your omega is what is normally called k (for reaction constant).  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_rate_constant